# Ruby: How to determine if file being read is binary or text

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am writing a program in Ruby which will search for strings in text files within a directory - similar to Grep.

I don't want it to attempt to search in binary files but I can't find a way in Ruby to determine whether a file is binary or text.

The program needs to work on both Windows and Linux.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks,

Xanthalas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gem install ptools
require 'ptools'
File.binary?(file)
```

Comment: Thanks johannes & quadruplebucky. I would vote both answers up but I don't yet have the required 15 reputation.

Comment: -1. ptools is not 100% accurate. you should use mime types instead

Comment: The ptools method will identify UTF-8 text files written in non-latin characters (Chinese, etc) as "binary". As @puchu said, use mime types instead.

Answer (score 13):

libmagic is a library which detects filetypes. For this solution I assume, that all mimetype's which start with `text/` represent text files. Eveything else is a binary file. This assumption is not correct for all mime types (eg. application/x-latex, application/json), but libmagic detect's these as text/plain.

```
require "filemagic"

def binary?(filename)
  begin
    fm= FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME)
    !(fm.file(filename)=~ /^text\//)
  ensure
    fm.close
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help. Note that you need the [ruby-filemagic](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) gem to run this code.

Comment: Note you can use `foo !~ bar` instead of `!(foo =~ bar)`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using the `ruby-filemagic` gem is to rely on the `file` command that ships with most Unix-like operating systems. I believe it uses the same `libmagic` library under the hood but you don't need the development files required to compile the `ruby-filemagic` gem. This is helpful if you're in an environment where it's a bit of work to install additional libraries (e.g. Heroku).

According to `man file`, text files will usually contain the word `text` in their description:

```
$ file Gemfile
Gemfile: ASCII text
```

You can run the file command through Ruby can capture the output:

```
require "open3"

def text_file?(filename)
  file_type, status = Open3.capture2e("file", filename)
  status.success? && file_type.include?("text")
end
```

Comment: Are you implying that heroku doesn't have the required libraries for this to work?

Comment: I think when I tried to use ruby-filemagic on Heroku it failed to compile due to missing development files, but that was a few years ago. I'm not sure if their newer stacks come with libmagic-dev. You could also use a custom buildpack to add the missing library on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Updating above answer with such example, when file name includes "text":

```
file /tmp/ball-texture.png
/tmp/ball-texture.png: PNG image data, 11 x 18, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

So updated code will be like:

```
def text_file?(filename)
  file_type, status = Open3.capture2e('file', filename)
  status.success? && file_type.split(':').last.include?('text')
end
```