# How to check if PDF, DOC or DOCX file is password protected in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way through which I can identify if the file that has been uploaded by the user is password protected? We have a scenario where we do not want our users to upload password protected files in our app that's built on Ruby on Rails.

File types will either be `PDF` or a Word Document (`DOC` or `DOCX`)

Comment: What file type? If you say ”any”, then it's impossible to do what you want.

Comment: Word and PDF files

Comment: @nurav By "Word Document" you mean modern `.docx` or legacy `doc` files also?

Comment: It could be both of them, but in case it isn't possible to restrict on legacy doc files then we can apply that as a requisite for the user to upload the file.

Comment: For pdf files that are encrypted using Adobe's encryption option, consider using a gem such as [preflight](https://github.com/yob/pdf-preflight). I'm not familiar with it but I see one of the "rules" that can be applied is `Preflight::Rules::NoEncryption`.  If a gem designed to read pdf or Word files cannot open the file, it may indicate the file is encrypted. If the encrypted files are always binary, the gem *ruby-filemagic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355866/ruby-how-to-determine-if-file-being-read-is-binary-or-text) can be used to determine if the file is binary.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any Ruby library that can be used for that kind of task.

But you may call external tools like `docx2txt` and `pdftotext` from Ruby code. For encrypted files calling these tools results in printing message to STDERR and returning non-zero exit code.

Let's have a look at this demo code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'open3'

file_names = ARGV   
command = ""

file_names.each do |file_name|
  case file_name
  when /.\.pdf$/i
    command = "pdftotext #{file_name} -"
  when /.\.docx$/i
    command = "docx2txt #{file_name} -"
  else
    next
  end

  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command)

  puts "command: #{command}"
  puts "stdout:  #{stdout}"
  puts "stderr:  #{stderr}"
  puts "status:  #{status}"
  puts   
end
```

I created four files for pdf and docx with self explanatory names: `pass.docx`, `pass.pdf`, `no_pass.docx`, `no_pass.pdf` and executed above script:

```
./tester.rb pass.pdf pass.docx no_pass.pdf no_pass.docx
command: pdftotext pass.pdf -
stdout:  
stderr:  Command Line Error: Incorrect password
status:  pid 5856 exit 1

command: docx2txt pass.docx -
stdout:  
stderr:  Failed to extract required information from <pass.docx>!
status:  pid 5860 exit 2

command: pdftotext no_pass.pdf -
stdout:  Hello world.
stderr:  
status:  pid 5866 exit 0

command: docx2txt no_pass.docx -
stdout:  Hello world.
stderr:  
status:  pid 5870 exit 0
```

At least for PDF you can determine if a file is password protected if you call `pdftotext` without providing a valid password (specified with `-upw` argument). Just watch for `Command Line Error: Incorrect password` stderr message.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a tool for `docx` that returns an unambiguous error message in that case - there might be other reasons why `docx2txt` fails to convert file with `Failed to extract required information from <pass.docx>!` message and that will require further investigation.

Comment: It's worth noting that Ruby's `case` statement can handle multiple regular expressions and is a lot less messy than a series of `if` statements.

Comment: Another thing to note here is using [`File.extname`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-extname) which extracts the file extension without need for regular expressions. Then you can boil that `case` down to a simple hash lookup table. It's also important to account for spaces in filenames, interpolation is never enough when running commands. Use discrete arguments, like `open3(cmd, file_name, "-")` etc.